# PHP & MYSQL Order By Decimal Column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running a really simple MySQL query and trying to order the data by sale value... the column in the database is set to decimal(16,2) but when the data comes back it isn't sorted in any order.

Here is my code:

```
$query = "
SELECT *
     , SUM(sale_value) 
  FROM sale 
 WHERE week_no = $today
 GROUP  
    BY user_id 
 ORDER 
    BY sale_value DESC
"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "Total ". $row['user_id']. " = &pound;". $row['SUM(sale_value)'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

And here is the result I get:

```
Total 14 = £2195.77
Total 62 = £865.01
Total 52 = £2989.53
Total 42 = £2689.47
Total 51 = £894.51
Total 48 = £962.09
Total 39 = £1161.43
Total 33 = £1341.49
Total 1 = £5989.57
Total 8 = £4937.48
Total 59 = £1377.70
Total 32 = £3063.06
Total 41 = £1937.82
Total 60 = £2981.01
Total 53 = £1050.21
Total 46 = £1836.05
Total 57 = £310.43
Total 19 = £2534.92
Total 5 = £1946.01
Total 56 = £471.00
Total 7 = £865.00
Total 2 = £754.30
```

Can anyone spot what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `SUM(sale_value) AS total` and then `ORDER BY total DESC`?

Comment: SELECT * .. GROUP BY..  er, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ordering by an *arbitrary* value in a matching row, not the sum.  Give the column an alias and use that:

```
SELECT *, SUM(sale_value) as total_sale_value
FROM sale
WHERE week_no = ".$today."
GROUP  BY user_id
ORDER By total_sale_value DESC;
```

By the way, `select *` is a really, really, really bad idea to use with `group by`.  You should explicit list the columns used to define each aggregation group:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(sale_value) as total_sale_value
FROM sale
WHERE week_no = ".$today."
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER By total_sale_value DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `order by SUM(sale_value)` not `sale_value`